# jQuery code get attr issue

Tags: jquery

I have elements created dynamically using php with the id of feed_container. I want each individual element to be able to be faded seperately. I tried to accomplish this by giving each element a specific class name and then using jquery to get that class and then fade, but nothing happens. The jquery code is below. Everything that I've researched says I'm doing it right. Is there anything wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#feed_container").click(function(){
    var $key = $("#feed_container").attr('class');
    $key.fadeTo("slow",0.15);
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: or `var $key = this.className`..

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the elements by class first before using fadeTo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#feed_container").click(function(){
    var $key = $("#feed_container").attr('class');
    $('.' + $key).fadeTo("slow",0.15);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement returns a string, not a jQuery object

```
$("#feed_container").attr('class')
```

So you can't use

```
var $key = $("#feed_container").attr('class');
$key.fadeTo("slow",0.15);
```

Because $key is a string and doesn't have a `fadeTo` method

Maybe you meant

```
$("#feed_container").fadeTo(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply fade the container out instead of getting the class first? You already have the element in `$(this)`:

```
$("#feed_container").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
});
```

If you have multiple elements, assign a class instead:

```
$(".feed_container").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
});
```